# xpath selection of html results in element response

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

```
from lxml import html
import requests

url = 'https://www.data.gov/'
r = requests.get(url)
doc = html.fromstring(r.content)
link = doc.xpath('/html/body/header/div[4]/div/div/h4/label/small/a')
print(link)
```

This keeps giving me:

```
[Element a at 0x1c64c963f48]
```

response instead the actual number I am seeking in the page?  Any idea why?
Also, why can't I get a `type(link)` value to see the type?

Answer (score 5):

Try below code to get `"192,322"` as output:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
url = 'https://www.data.gov/'
r = requests.get(url)
doc = html.fromstring(r.content)
try:
    link = doc.xpath('//a[@href="/metrics"]/text()')[0]
    print(link.split()[0])
except IndexError:
    print("No link found")
```

Comment: `doc.xpath('//a[@href="/metrics"]/text()')[0]` will produce a run-time error when nothing was found.

Comment: I'd probably just use `if (link):` (the empty list evaluates to false), but any check is better than no check.

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath gives you `<a>` elements. You want their text. So... print their text.

```
link = doc.xpath("//label[@for='search-header']//a")

for a in link:
    print( a.text )
```

Notes

- `/html/body/header/div[4]/div/div/h4/label/small/a` is *way* too specific. It will break very easily when they make even the slightest change to their HTML layout. Don't use auto-generated XPath expressions. Write all your XPath expressions yourself.
- XPath always returns a list of nodes, even if there is only one hit. Use a loop or pick a specific list item (like `link[0]`).

Comment: thx for your input.  I should have been more specific.  I am trying to get a string to parse or the actual number 192,322 out of that webpage.  what your approach returns is the href "/metrics".  Any thoughts?

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the feature for extracting the href by changing your code to use the `text()`. See below:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

url = 'https://www.data.gov/'
r = requests.get(url)
doc = html.fromstring(r.content)
link = doc.xpath('/html/body/header/div[4]/div/div/h4/label/small/a/text()')
print(link)
```

Example in Chrome Developer Tools:

```
> $x("/html/body/header/div[4]/div/div/h4/label/small/a/text()")[0]
> 192,322 DATASETS
```

Comment: Thx for input.  That doesn't return the value 192,322 or a string to parse, which is what I was targeting.  I am copy/pasting xpath value of chrome inspect element and I need to return the value or string to parse in regex.  Why is it giving me an 'element' value response?

Comment: Never copy and paste machine-generated XPath. Learn XPath. Build your XPath expressions yourself.

Comment: is it safer for a newbie to start with csselect then ?  I was trying to learn all approaches possible.

Comment: @aland I agree with Tomalank that you should learn to write xpath. That being said, if you change the `@href` to `text()` that will work. Check my answer now (with Chrome example)

Comment: @aland Learning XPath to the level necessary to write better XPath than any machine takes an hour, most probably less. Wondering if you might want to do something else first is a waste of time.